# Java RMI : connection refused

Tags: java, rmi

I have written following code for the client of RMI. But getting

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested 
exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

code :

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;

class client
{
    public static void main(String [] ars)
    {
        Iface serv;
        Registry r;
        String serveraddr = ars[0];
        String serverport = ars[1];
        String text = "Hey jude";

        System.out.println("Sending" + text);

        try{
            r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(
            serveraddr,
            (new Integer(serverport)).intValue()
            );
            serv = (Iface) r.lookup("rmi://server");

            serv.receive(text);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're getting that on bind, rebind, or lookup, the Registry isn't running. If you get it doing the remote call, see item A.1 in the [RMI FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html) supplied with the Javadoc, and if you're running Linux also check that your /etc/hosts file maps 127.0.0.1 to localhost and your real ip address to your real hostname - this has been a common problem in some Linux distributions.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem. It's silly but just that I forgot to start the RMI registry process.

So, you also need to run RMI Registry process

```
rmiregistry
```

Before you try to rebind(address, obj) with RMI registry.